# How do I encode and decode a base64 string?

Tags: c#, base64

1. How do I return a base64 encoded string given a string?
2. How do I decode a base64 encoded string into a string?

Comment: If this is a "sharing the knowledge" question and answer, I think we're looking for something a bit more in-depth. Also a quick search of SO turns up: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7368168/419

Comment: Ask yourself do you really need to do this? Remember base64 is primarily intended for representing binary data in ASCII, for storing in a char field in  a database or sending via email (where new lines could be injected). Do you really want to take character data, convert it to bytes, then convert it back to character data, this time unreadable and with no hint of what the original encoding was ?

Comment: Why should we care about the original encoding? We encode the string into the bytes using UTF8 representation, which can represent all the possible string characters. We then serialize that data and on the other end we deserialize that data and we reconstruct the same string that we originally had (string object doesn't hold the information about encoding used anyway). So why is there any concern related to the encoding used? We can consider it like a proprietary way of representing the serialized data, which we shouldn't be interested at anyway.

Answer (score 2392, accepted):

### Encode

```
public static string Base64Encode(string plainText) 
{
  var plainTextBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plainText);
  return System.Convert.ToBase64String(plainTextBytes);
}
```

### Decode

```
public static string Base64Decode(string base64EncodedData) 
{
  var base64EncodedBytes = System.Convert.FromBase64String(base64EncodedData);
  return System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(base64EncodedBytes);
}
```

Answer (score 16):

URL safe Base64 Encoding/Decoding

```
public static class Base64Url
{
    public static string Encode(string text)
    {
        return Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text)).TrimEnd('=').Replace('+', '-')
            .Replace('/', '_');
    }

    public static string Decode(string text)
    {
        text = text.Replace('_', '/').Replace('-', '+');
        switch (text.Length % 4)
        {
            case 2:
                text += "==";
                break;
            case 3:
                text += "=";
                break;
        }
        return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(text));
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that using `Replace()` and `TrimEnd()` several times in a row will allocate new strings that will instantly become garbage for the GC. Instead, you can use `StringBuilder` with a specified capacity to avoid the extra heap allocations.

Answer (score 5):

For those that simply want to encode/decode individual base64 digits:

```
public static int DecodeBase64Digit(char digit, string digit62 = "+-.~", string digit63 = "/_,")
{
    if (digit >= 'A' && digit <= 'Z') return digit - 'A';
    if (digit >= 'a' && digit <= 'z') return digit + (26 - 'a');
    if (digit >= '0' && digit <= '9') return digit + (52 - '0');
    if (digit62.IndexOf(digit) > -1)  return 62;
    if (digit63.IndexOf(digit) > -1)  return 63;
    return -1;
}

public static char EncodeBase64Digit(int digit, char digit62 = '+', char digit63 = '/')
{
    digit &= 63;
    if (digit < 52)
        return (char)(digit < 26 ? digit + 'A' : digit + ('a' - 26));
    else if (digit < 62)
        return (char)(digit + ('0' - 52));
    else
        return digit == 62 ? digit62 : digit63;
}
```

There are [various versions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) of Base64 that disagree about what to use for digits 62 and 63, so `DecodeBase64Digit` can tolerate several of these.