# Converting curl command to C# code

Tags: c#, api, curl, http-headers

I am having problems converting a curl command to c# code.

I have been given a curl command which includes an API key as follows:

```
curl -k -u x:459c4da6401d39bbf9327ee17175e25c 
        -H "Content-Type: application/json" https://disney.com/v1/services.json
```

When I watch this call in Fiddler I can see a header value that looks like this:

```
Authorization: Basic eDo0NTljNGRhNjQwMWQzOWJiZjkzMjdlZTE3MTc1ZTI1Yw==
```

So, the curl command is working perfectly... But I cannot replicate it in c# code

I don't understand how the `x:459c4da6401d39bbf9327ee17175e25c` has changed to `Authorization: Basic eDo0NTljNGRhNjQwMWQzOWJiZjkzMjdlZTE3MTc1ZTI1Yw==`

And subsequently, I am confused how to get my c# code to change from the API key to what I am seeing in Fiddler.

When I use this code to add a header the authorisation fails:

```
httpWebRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", "459c4da6401d39bbf9327ee17175e25c");
```

I have also tried:

```
httpWebRequest.Headers["Authorization"] = "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("459c4da6401d39bbf9327ee17175e25c"));
```

But that produces a header value of this:

```
Authorization: Basic NDU5YzRkYTY0MDFkMzliYmY5MzI3ZWUxNzE3NWUyNWM=
```

Can anyone help please?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`eDo0NTljNGRhNjQwMWQzOWJiZjkzMjdlZTE3MTc1ZTI1Yw==` is the base64 encode of `x:459c4da6401d39bbf9327ee17175e25c`. Try [online here](http://base64encode.net/).

And the request header for Authorization will be the base64 string that you encoded above.

```
httpWebRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic eDo0NTljNGRhNjQwMWQzOWJiZjkzMjdlZTE3MTc1ZTI1Yw==");
```

You can use [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11743160/how-do-i-encode-and-decode-a-base64-string) to perform base64 encoding/decoding in `c#`.

Comment: thanks! so, I was an idiot and I was encoding without the "x:" which I thought was a curl parameter....