# UPS ZPL Lable size issue I need small size label for my ZP450 printer

Tags: printing, size, label, ups

I want to show the UPS Label size in the following size Width = 4 inches and Height = 8 Inches

But UPS API returns the GraphicImage in base64 format when I display it on my browser Like

it display the very large size image on my browser Like width:1400px and Height:800px;

when I print this image on my ZP450 printer it printed very small image on page even that is not readable on page.

any help is much appreciated, how I display the small level image on browser

or send the print directly using base64 code But I want to print image size large when it printed on page Like UPS.COM printed.

Comment: have you find any solution for the same?

Answer (score 3):

Before sending a UPS GraphicImage label using ZPL format to a Zebra Printer, you need to convert it from base64 string to ascii string.  See the answer to [How do I Encode and Decode a base64 string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11743160/how-do-i-encode-and-decode-a-base64-string)

```
//...UPS Shipment Request construction...
shipmentRequest.LabelSpecification.LabelImageFormat.Code = "ZPL";
shipmentRequest.LabelSpecification.LabelStockSize.Height = "8";
shipmentRequest.LabelSpecification.LabelStockSize.Width = "4";
//...
// Submit the Shipment Request to the UPS Ship Service
ShipmentResponse shipmentResponse = shipService.ProcessShipment(shipmentRequest);
//...Process the Shipment Response...

// The Label is encoded as Base64 Text.  Decode this to standard ASCII Text
string labelData = Base64Decode(shipmentResponse.ShipmentResults.PackageResults[0].ShippingLabel.GraphicImage);

// Write the label data to a file so it can be printed/reprinted as needed
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"C:\temp\UPSlabel.zpl", labelData);
```

The ZPL Label should be printed as RAW using a Generic Text printer driver.  You can edit and probably print the label using Notepad as long as you turn off its word-wrap, margins, header/footer/page number settings.  Notepad++ works.

I think this is also true for UPS EPL formatted labels.

Answer (score 0):

In new versions of their API, they do not have `LabelSpecification` object so this solution might help you. These settings would help you for a thermal printer:

```
shipment.Documents = new DocumentsType();
shipment.Documents.Image = new ImageType[1];
shipment.Documents.Image[0] = new ImageType();
shipment.Documents.Image[0].Type = new ShipCodeDescriptionType();
shipment.Documents.Image[0].Type.Code = "30";
shipment.Documents.Image[0].PrintFormat = new ShipCodeDescriptionType();
shipment.Documents.Image[0].PrintFormat.Code = "02"; // thermal
shipment.Documents.Image[0].Format = new ShipCodeDescriptionType();
shipment.Documents.Image[0].Format.Code = "01"; // pdf
shipment.Documents.Image[0].LabelsPerPage = "1";
shipment.Documents.Image[0].PrintSize = new PrintSizeType();
shipment.Documents.Image[0].PrintSize.Length = "4";
shipment.Documents.Image[0].PrintSize.Width = "6";
```

From above code, you can see because they are accepting an array for image settings, this means it should return multiple images with different specifications.

And this is how I am converting the returned label image and saving it onto the server:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(base64) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(extension))
{
    byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64);

    var path = "~/ShippingLabels/UPS";

    if (!Directory.Exists(Server.MapPath(path)))
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(Server.MapPath(path));
    }

    var filePath = string.Format("{0}/{1}_{2}_{3}.{4}", path, freightShipResponse.ShipmentResults.BOLID, freightShipResponse.ShipmentResults.ShipmentNumber, DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddmmhhssfff"), extension);

    System.IO.FileStream stream = new FileStream(Server.MapPath(filePath), FileMode.CreateNew);
    System.IO.BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(stream);
    writer.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    writer.Close();
}
```