# PHP - byte[] to Blob

Tags: c#, php, xamarin

I'm attempting so send over a `byte[]` using HTTP Post to store into a MySQL database as an image but it's not encoding the `byte[]` correctly or I'm simply doing something very wrong.

**C# Code**

```cs
public async Task<string> Post (byte[] image)
    {
        string data = data = string.Format ("METHOD=post&Image={0}", image);

        HttpWebRequest r = await Info.createRequest (data);
        using (var resp = await Task.Factory.FromAsync<WebResponse> (r.BeginGetResponse, r.EndGetResponse, null)) {
            return "Finished";
        }
    }

/*Info.createRequest(data)*/
public static async Task<HttpWebRequest> createRequest (string json, string ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", byte[] img = null)
    {
        (new CancellationTokenSource ()).Dispose ();
        var request = WebRequest.Create (BaseUrl) as HttpWebRequest; 
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = ContentType;

        byte[] postData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes (json);

        using (var stream = await Task.Factory.FromAsync<Stream> (request.BeginGetRequestStream, request.EndGetRequestStream, request)) {
            await stream.WriteAsync (postData, 0, postData.Length);
            /*if (img != null)
                await stream.WriteAsync (img, 0, img.Length);*/
            //^ Didn't seme to work. 
        }

        return request;
    }
```

**PHP Code**

```php
$null = NULL;
        $stmt = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO Posts (Image) VALUES (?)");
        $stmt->bind_param("b", $_POST["Image"]);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->close();
```

Comment: try `$stmt->bind_param("b", $_POST["file"]);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string.Format("METHOD=post&Image={0}", image);
```

Will yield something like:

```
METHOD=post&Image=System.Byte[]
```

So nothing useful will be actually sent.

You can use [Base64 encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11743160/how-do-i-encode-and-decode-a-base64-string) if you want to POST the binary data:

```
String base64 = System.Convert.ToBase64String(image)
string.Format("METHOD=post&Image={0}", base64 );
```

I am not sure how the reverse operation is done in PHP, but I think it is something using [base64_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-decode.php):

```
$base64Image = base64_decode($_POST["Image"]);
```

Answer (score 2):

Using .NET 4.5 (you can use .NET 4.0 by adding the [Microsoft.Net.Http](http://nuget.org/Packages/Microsoft.Net.Http) package from NuGet) there is an easier way to simulate form requests.

Here is an example:

```
private System.IO.Stream Upload(string actionUrl, string paramString, Stream paramFileStream, byte [] paramFileBytes)
{
    HttpContent stringContent = new StringContent(paramString);
    HttpContent fileStreamContent = new StreamContent(paramFileStream);
    HttpContent bytesContent = new ByteArrayContent(paramFileBytes);
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    using (var formData = new MultipartFormDataContent())
    {
        formData.Add(stringContent, "param1", "param1");
        formData.Add(fileStreamContent, "file1", "file1");
        formData.Add(bytesContent, "file2", "file2");
        var response = client.PostAsync(actionUrl, formData).Result;
        if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            return null;
        }
        return response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result;
    }
}
```