# Retrieve BASE64 encryption from AJAX call

Tags: c#

I am working on a scraper and I got stuck trying to figure out a base64 encrypted data being passed through AJAX that contains a products Size and Color information.

Sample product URL:
http://merchant.com/MARC-by-Marc-Jacobs-Orion-Metallic-Taffeta-1950s-Dress-Black/prod174690614/p.prod?eVar4=You%20May%20Also%20Like&RST=CategorySiloedViewCP

Using Fiddler, I can see that it calls an AJAX service to retrieve the sizes and colors for this product: http://merchant.com/productserviceAJAX

It passes the following string: 
data=$b64$eyJQcm9kdWN0U2l6ZUFuZENvbG9yIjp7InByb2R1Y3RJZHMiOiJwcm9kMTc0NjkwNjE0In19&timestamp=1424678606863

I need to be able to determine how to recreate the above string to be able to pass it to the service and I can get the returned JSON string from the AJAX call.

Comment: Just put that data in double quotes and voila, you have a string literal that you can pass around. (But I suppose that's not what you really wanted to know.)

Comment: the 64-bit string is different for every product URL, so I cannot use the same string for all product URL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not an encryption, that's an encoding. Decode the base64 string, e.g. using [an online tool](https://www.base64decode.org/) and look at the result:

```
{"ProductSizeAndColor":{"productIds":"prod174690614"}}
```

This is a JSON expression, the product ID appears in your Sample product URL, so you should be able to construct a Base64 string from a given URL using [C# Base64 methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11743160/how-do-i-encode-and-decode-a-base64-string).

Comment: How did you come up with the result? I did try using that tool earlier, I must have given it the wrong string to decode. What string did you use?

Comment: LOL thanks figured it out, I encoded the JSON you gave and found the string I was asking for, GENIUS!

Comment: I used the string between the second `$` sign and the `&` sign: `eyJQcm9kdWN0U2l6ZUFuZENvbG9yIjp7InByb2R1Y3RJZHMiOiJwcm9kMTc0NjkwNjE0In19`