# How can I send a complicated string from C# to PHP?

Tags: c#, php, string, webclient

I'm building a level into a C# string using each char to hold two different elements.  I'm using all 16 bits in each char.  I'm able to save the level off in a text file and read it back in with no issues.  It's ugly to look at because a number of chars match something that equals null.  When I tried sending it to PHP (code below) I immediately echoed back the string I received.  Upon first glance the data was wrong.  Upon checking the bits in each string I could see that there was no real relation between the two strings that were supposed to be the same.

```
    public static void UploadLevel(int userID, string levelData)
    {
        Debug.Log("LEVEL OUT:");
        Scene_Editor.LevelToBinary(levelData);
        using (var client = new WebClient())
        {
            var values = new NameValueCollection();
            values["uid"] = userID.ToString();
            values["leveldata"] = levelData;

            var response = client.UploadValues("http://example.com/uploadlevel.php", values);

            var responseString = System.Text.Encoding.UTF32.GetString(response);
            Debug.Log("levelData BACK");
            Scene_Editor.LevelToBinary(responseString);
        }
    }
```

And here is uploadlevel.php

```
<?php
   echo $_POST['leveldata'];
?>
```

Here is a very short example of a level converted to a string (3 chars is the smallest, and can go up to 99 chars).

Level Out: ㄐ
Broken down into binary:
0) 0010001011111111 (no char seems to be associated with this value)
1) 0011000100010000 (ㄐ)
2) 0010000001100000 (no char seems to be associated with this value)

Level Back: 询還
Broken down into binary:
0) 1000101111100010 (询)
1) 1001000010000100 (還)

Now, I don't even necessarily need this to be a string as long as I can store it in a database and get it back and convert the bits back into a level.  Any ideas?  Also, I'm using .net 4.0.

Comment: can you show us an example input string and output?

Comment: i dnt know wheather your data is being sent as get or post. instead of using $_POST use $_REQUEST because request accept both get and post.

Comment: "number of chars match something that equals null" <- What does that mean? Are you using `===` to compare or just `==`? Also, if you're dealing with binary it is FAR less error prone to base64 encode/decode it when moving it between languages like that.

Comment: @ devlin: I added an example to the original post.

Comment: jewelhuq: It is using $_POST.  I've got a few other pages and commands working before I tried this tricky one and they've all used post.  And since I'm getting data back from post it's clearly set.

@Mike: I mean that it doesn't seem to have any char associated with that binary combination.  I've added an example in the main post.  I'm not using === or ==, I'm breaking the answer down into binary and visually making sure it's the same.  How would I get started on base64 encode/decode?

Comment: @Califer See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11743160/how-do-i-encode-and-decode-a-base64-string for C# and for PHP you would do `base64_decode($_POST['leveldata'])`.