# Byte[32] converts to string with Convert.ToBase64String(byteValue32) but to go opposite the Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(string) becomes byte[44]

Tags: c#, encoding, base64, byte, arrays

So it seems like the conversion is not the same

example

```
byte[] salt;  // this i hover over and see {byte[32]}  
string saltText = Convert.ToBase64String(salt);
// This saltText come out with the string

// example is that saltText = puYwD1RHO9mdrg4eakJIskcrN4wPlxzkBwjdwyJL+Eg=
```

This part is just fine, however I was in need of converting it back so I did this

```
byte[] saltArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(saltText);

// Hover over and the saltArray is saying {byte[44]}
```

Am I not understanding Bytes ?  **Why is is changing from 32 to 44** ??

Comment: try this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11743160/how-do-i-encode-and-decode-a-base64-string

Comment: Because you first convert to base-64 string, and then treat that as ASCII encoded string. Why would you expect that to work at all? Use Convert.FromBase64String instead.

Comment: Thanks,  not use to working with this stuff at all,  and I simply found the other code on SO , but clearly must had been for some other use case.

Comment: Well, your string of text is 44 characters so that is exactly what you are getting with ASCII...    OP is correct    Convert.FromBase64String is what you want instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this for decoding

```
var base64EncodedBytes = System.Convert.FromBase64String(salt);
var stringData = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(base64EncodedBytes);
```

Comment: BTW,  I'm only using the 1st line   var base64EncodedBytes , I only needed that... that is working fine.   I don't need the second line of taking it back to a string,  but something is not right with that , I get a lot of funny ascii characters...  fyi

Comment: "�hr]��Y�C}�\0pC��A���\v!;c�g\vE"

Comment: please add your simple input & expected output?

Comment: string salt = "1mhyXbq7WdsXQ32IAHBDGtbzQQWKjKELIRw7Y6lnC0U=";
var base64EncodedBytes = System.Convert.FromBase64String(salt);
base64EncodedBytes.Dump();   // 32 items in byte array 
var stringData = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(base64EncodedBytes);
stringData.Dump();   //  �hr]��Y�C}�pC��A��� !;c�g E

Comment: string saltText = Convert.ToBase64String(base64EncodedBytes);    that seems to convert it back properly

Comment: What is your the source of byte[] salt=?. data & how you get that? I think there was a problem with your source.

Comment: public static byte[] GetSalt(int size = 32)
        {
            byte[] salt = new byte[size];
            using (var cryptoServiceProvider = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider())
            {
                cryptoServiceProvider.GetBytes(salt);
            }
            return salt;
        }

Comment: I think it provide you the correct character as your input string if the ASCII is less than 128. � is for Extended ASCII Codes, when your ASCII values is more than 127. see here http://www.asciitable.com/