# Why does my C# escape character not work when being decoded from base 64?

Tags: c#, stringescapeutils

I make a simple printing app where I use `\n`, `\t` to text format like tab or new line.

It is run perfectly when I input using hard code like this.

```
isi = "ARIEF - JL. ANGGA JAYA II\n\t\t\t\tSTRUK PEMBAYARAN NEXXT MEDIA\n\nIDPEL\t\t\t: 09343590348509435\nTGL. BAYAR\t\t: 2017-09-02 10:26:53 \t\t\tTAGIHAN\t: 1.000.000\nPRODUK\t\t:\t\t\t\t\tADMIN\t\t: 2.500\nNAMA\t\t\t: RYAN\t\t\t\t\tTOTAL\t\t: 1.500.000\nREF\t\t\t: ARIEF - JL. ANGGA JAYA II\n\n\t\t\tCATUR TUNGGAL KAB SLEMAN DAISTA YOGYAKARTA\n\n\t\t\tSTRUK INI MERUPAKAN BUKTI PEMBAYARAN YANG SAH\n\t\t\t     HUBUNGI CUSTOMER SUPPORT LOKET PPOB ANDA\n";
```

and runs like this:

[image]

But when I acquire the string from base64 decode using this code:

```
public string base64ToString(string str)
{
    byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String(str);
    return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data).ToString();
}
```

it doesn't escape format anymore and get this layout:

[image]

Is there something wrong with my code? Or am I missing some basic C# knowledge?

Here is UTF-8 base64 encoded string:

```
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
```

I got that string by using this:

[image]

Comment: I think there might be something wrong with your base64 string. Can you post that here?

Comment: thanks for your reply, i have edit my question.

Comment: How did you encode that string? Apparently you added literal `\n` and `\t` in your strings rather than newlines and tabs.

Comment: @JeffMercado, yess, i simply encoded the isi variable's value.

Comment: Probably there's something wrong with the encoding function. The encoded string I get is different from yours. See this for [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11743162/5894241).

Comment: That's the problem, you encoded it incorrectly. Show us how you got the encoded string in the first place.

Comment: @NisargShah, i use tools online, i don't use C# encoded because it is work like cross platform, the string is compose by other programming language.

Comment: @JeffMercado, i have update my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tool you used was not the right tool for the job. It took the literal text you pasted in there (backslashes and all) and converted it to a base64 string. From a programmer's perspective, it changed `\n` to `"\\n"`. For that tool to work, you cannot enter `\n` and expect to see a newline, you need to actually type in a newline character. Same for `\t`, you need to type in actual tab characters (assuming that tool doesn't do any additional processing on the data).

It would just be easier to encode it in code.

```
string EncodeString(string str, Encoding encoding = null)
{
    encoding = encoding ?? Encoding.UTF8;
    return Convert.ToBase64String(encoding.GetBytes(str));
}
string DecodeString(string str, Encoding encoding = null)
{
    encoding = encoding ?? Encoding.UTF8;
    return encoding.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(str));
}
```

Comment: ahhh,,, you are right,,,,
the string \t was converted to \\t by encoder tool...
thankyou...
my though doesn't reach there...
thumbs up for u sir...