# How to encode IP for GET request in api in .NET

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to figure out how to send IP in GET request. I want to call GET request like : `/api/endpoint/12.12.12.12`. I tried to encode it but `HttpUtility.UrlEncode` won't encode dots for IP alone. When I try use `%2E` as dot then IIS throws `404.11 - The request filtering module is configured to deny a request that contains a double escape sequence.`. How to I make it the right way?

Comment: Why do you want to encode the IP anyway? Why not just send it as it is?

Comment: what is the problem if you just send the IP as is? it does not contain any special character which need to be escaped

Comment: BTW what happens if you send it *as is* with dots?

Comment: send it as string

Comment: @Gusman If you use periods, some servers (like IIS) can get confused and think it's a static file unless you modify the web.config

Comment: @DavidG Then replace `.` with `-` ?

Comment: @ErikKralj Well that's why OP is asking how to encode it...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dots in URL causes 404 with ASP.NET mvc and IIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11728846/dots-in-url-causes-404-with-asp-net-mvc-and-iis)

Comment: @Meroz There is no need to encode the IP. Send it as is or replace `.` with something else. If you try running `encodeURIComponent('12.12.12.12')` you will see the result is still `'12.12.12.12'`

Comment: If you know the IP address is IPv4, then you can use the `Address` property  and pass the IP around as a `long`. Otherwise the `GetAddressBytes` method and send those as comma separated. There's a million ways to do it.

Comment: I tried already replacing "." with "-" but wonder if there's another, proper solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to encode it  in base 64. You can find how to do it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11743162/1381952)

/api/endpoint/MTIuMTIuMTIuMTI=

Answer (score 0):

You could just do a string replace.

`"12.12.12.12".Replace(".","%2E");`

Comment: IIS see it as secority issue and gives me `404.11 - The request filtering module is configured to deny a request that contains a double escape sequence.`. I wrote it in question.

Answer (score 0):

Add a slash at the end of the URL:

```
/api/endpoint/12.12.12.12/
```

this should work

Comment: My IIS configuration won't allow it. It recognize it as file as @DavidG wrote