# How to implement base64 decode method into a gridview?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, base64

I have a data binding method to bind a gridview to the database.

```
 private void BindGrid()
{
    string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr);
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select bookingId, bookingName, fprice from addCart");

    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter();

    cmd.Connection = con;
    sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
    using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
    {
    sda.Fill(dt);
    GridView1.DataSource = dt;
    GridView1.DataBind();
    }
    con.Close();            
}
```

As I had previously used a base64 encoding method to encode the bookingId and bookingName, the data displayed in the gridview shows only the encoded values. How do I add in a base64 decoding method such that it displays decoded value in the gridview?

How I used my encoding:

```
byte[] serviceEncode = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(serviceLabel.Text);

sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@bookingName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Convert.ToBase64String(serviceEncode);
```

Database value: QgBpAGMAeQBjAGwAZQAmACMAMwAyADsA

I had previously used an html decoding method in my item template. I am wondering if there is any similar known method to decode using base64?

```
 <ItemTemplate>
 <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" decoding="base64" Text='<%# HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(Eval("bookingName").ToString()) %>'></asp:Label>                   
 </ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: A) You can iterate over the rows of the datatable and set the Base64 decoded values in a new column, before setting the datasource. (B) You can use the row data found event of the grid view to decode the data.

Comment: can I have the exact codes on how to do it? I am quite new to this. @NisargShah

Comment: change `<%# HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(Eval("bookingName").ToString()) %>` to
`<%# System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(Eval("bookingName").ToString()))%>`

Comment: I get this error: : Invalid length for a Base-64 char array or string.
 after making the above changes @levent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run a foreach inside the Datatable and update the rows with decoded values

```
string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr);
con.Open();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select bookingId, bookingName, fprice from addCart");

SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter();

cmd.Connection = con;
sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
         using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
                {
                    sda.Fill(dt);
                    foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
                    {
                        //decode the bookingid and bookingname and update in table
                       if(dr["bookingName"].ToString()!=""){
                        string newbookingname = "";
                    try { 
                    newbookingname = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(dr["bookingName"].ToString()));
                    }
                    catch(Exception e)
                    {
                        newbookingname = dr["bookingName"].ToString();
                    }
                    dr["bookingName"] = newbookingname;
                       }
                    }

                    GridView1.DataSource = dt;
                    GridView1.DataBind();
                }
con.Close();
```

and in gridview

```
    <ItemTemplate>
 <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server"  Text='<%# Eval("bookingName") %>'></asp:Label>                   
 </ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: May i know what does the Tables in dt.Tables[0].Rows stand for? I get an error when I copied that over into my codes @shubham

Comment: sorry, it should be just dt.Rows

Comment: Ok, I received no more error, however I got an error at the dr["bookingId"] part. @shubham the error says cannot convert from object to string

Comment: sda.Fill(dt);
this will be above the foreach. Please check code now

Comment: I have made the following amendments. Now the new error says: System.FormatException: Invalid length for a Base-64 char array or string, at the line with the encoding method@shubham

Comment: "I had previously used a base64 encoding method to encode the bookingId and bookingName" , are you sure you encoded both bookingId and bookingName and not just bookingName?

Comment: wait sorry i did not encode the bookingId, only the bookingName. I had commented out the bookingId line and renamed the second dr["bookingId"] to bookingName @shubham

Comment: that was what i had done and I still got that error @shubham

Comment: You might have to check your addCart table if there aren't any nulls or empty in bookingName field.

Comment: Im very sure there are no null values @shubham

Comment: its working for me, and the string you gave in your question is returning Bicycle&#32;. made changes, can check again

Comment: I got the same error even though I added in the changes. @shubham

Comment: Convert.FromBase64String(dr["bookingName"].ToString()); instead of this, write Convert.FromBase64String("QgBpAGMAeQBjAGwAZQAmACMAMwAyADsA"); so you can be sure if its a problem with table data

Comment: It still shows the encoded value, however I dont get any error, but it replace all my other values to Bicycle&#32 too@shubham

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164385/discussion-between-shubham-and-depressedgirl).

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function :

```
base64_decode('QgBpAGMAeQBjAGwAZQAmACMAMwAyADsA');
```

**Replace this:**

```
string newbookingname = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(dr["bookingName"].ToString()));
```

**With this:**

```
string textDecoded = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.DecodeBase64(<"Your encoded string">);
```

you can refer this for that error :
[How do I encode and decode a base64 string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11743160/how-do-i-encode-and-decode-a-base64-string)

Comment: May I know where exactly do I input this?

Comment: Bicycle&#32;       this is out put for above line.

Comment: yeah I know, i mean which part of my codes do i implement your suggestion? @Gajjar Parth

Comment: I got the error which says: Encoding does not contain a definition for DecodeBase64 @Gajjar Parth

Answer (score 0):

~this answer dose not have direct anwser it's just some recommend~

I've got this problem months ago , and i used to convert data first and then use it.

Recommend you to use Entity Framework.

It's more flexible than ADO.
Then u can use GUID type for ID's and its really easy to be shown any where.

For using EF , its better to use Database first then coding , by this technology you can create your database inside Visual studio and then EF can make models for you and BOOM all your hard codings are dismissed

And by using controllers you can easily get and set data's from database

Comment: I am very new to all these and I dont get what you mean by ADO, EF Entity Framework. But thanks for your suggestion @A. Razinejad