# c# decode byte[] sent from python socket

Tags: c#, json, python-3.6

In python, I convert a `dictionary` to a `json` `string`, use standard python `encoding`, then use `base64` to further `encode` for sending over a `socket` like this.

`item.data` is a `list` of `dicts`. `myconverter` is there to handle `datetime`.

```
UDP_IP = "127.0.0.1"
UDP_PORT = 5005

print("UDP target IP:", UDP_IP)
print("UDP target port:", UDP_PORT)

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, # Internet
                     socket.SOCK_DGRAM) # UDP

def myconverter(o):
    if isinstance(o, datetime.datetime):
        return o.__str__()


async def main_loop() 

....

    async for item in streamer.listen():
        for index, quoteDict in enumerate(item.data):
            quote = json.dumps(quoteDict, default = myconverter)

            sock.sendto(base64.b64encode(quote.encode('ascii')),  (UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))
```

When I use `python` to get the data sent over a `socket` like this, everything works fine:

```
import socket
import json
import base64


UDP_IP = "127.0.0.1"
UDP_PORT = 5005

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, # Internet
                     socket.SOCK_DGRAM) # UDP
sock.bind((UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))

while True:
    data, addr = sock.recvfrom(16384) # buffer size is 16384 bytes
    quote_dict = base64.b64decode(data)
    print(quote_dict)
```

**What is the equivalent section of `C#` code that `decodes` the `python` `enconded` `datagram` above?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I encode and decode a base64 string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11743160/how-do-i-encode-and-decode-a-base64-string)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work by:

Removing the conversion to `base64` in `python` by doing this:

```
sock.sendto(quote.encode('UTF-8'),  (UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))
```

Then in `C#`, I just use this function:

```
static string GetString(byte[] bytes) {
           return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes); }
```

Now I can read the data both from `python` and `C#`.

Answer (score 1):

You can decode a base 64 encoded string with the [Convert](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.frombase64string?view=netframework-4.7.2) class.

```
byte[] inputBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(inputText);
string decodedText = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(inputBytes);
```

**Important**

> The `FromBase64String` method is designed to process a single string
>   that contains all the data to be decoded. To decode base-64 character
>   data from a stream, use the
>   [System.Security.Cryptography.FromBase64Transform](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.frombase64transform?view=netframework-4.7.2) class.

Comment: When I use your suggestion and print out the string decodedText, it is a bunch of gibberish.

Comment: Can you show us your c# code for receiving the stream?