# Selenium Webdriver with Chrome browser not displaying authentication pop-up

Tags: selenium, authentication

I am automating an internal application of my client which is having LDAP authentication.
I am using Selenium 3.141.59 with C#, Chrome browser 78.

**Issue:**
    When I have open browser manually and place url then browser displaying sign-in Pop-up to enter the userID and password. (refer screenshot)  [image]

```
Same time when Selenium launch browser instance then navigate to same url, it's not showing any sign-in pop-up.
Due this I was unable to continue next steps in automation.
```

I have tried send the userID and password along with url as blow but it's also not redirecting.
https://userID:password@url

Can anyone help me, how to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

What you have tried is not supported any more. You now have to include authentication headers in requests. In your case I would recommend to set up a proxy which would add headers to all outcoming messages of your browser

For example you can use [Browsermob Proxy](https://www.nuget.org/packages/BrowserMobProxy/) that you can configure just in your tests. Some details of how basic authentication works you can find [here](https://webelement.click/en/http_header_selenium_webdriver_basic_authorization). It is solution for Java, however you can find which headers to set up and which values to assign (In short: header - `Authorization: Basic username:password Realm=""` where username:password is credentials pair encoded in `Base64`).

This also might be useful for you: [How do I encode and decode a base64 string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11743160/how-do-i-encode-and-decode-a-base64-string)

**UPD:** This is [solution for Python Selenium](https://www.webelement.click/en/four_simple_steps_to_add_custom_http_headers_in_selenium_webdriver_tests_in_python).