# XML parsing: end tag does not match start tag

Tags: xml

I have an xml. The value is from user input.

```
<Item id="36">
    <name>Electrical and lighting - Exterior lighting</name>
    <note><123comments></note>
    <info id="code">&*&^<samp&*></info>
</Item>
```

when saving the xml, I'm having an error "XML parsing: line 14, character 1868, end tag does not match start tag"

How can I can convert the value inside the node, without replacing the other < or >?

- in c# or js

Comment: The snippet is not valid XML.

Comment: Your XML is invalid. `<123comments>` is not valid content for an element.

Comment: @KenWhite and MrTux: Technically in XML terms, it's not [*well-formed*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25830482/290085).

Comment: thanks for your answers, is there a way on how to correct the value? but it will still save the same way, do I have to look for each tag?

Comment: XML must be well-formed, or it's not XML and it's not able to be used by XML libraries or tools.  I show in my answer one way to make your XML be well-formed; there are others.  If you'd like another way, you'll have to specify what you do not like about the way I showed you.  For example, you might say that you want `123comments` to be an opening tag; then, I'd say it must be closed and it must not start with a number.  And so on for any other variation you might ask about.  But you'll have to be specific about the variation.

Comment: Reading the link I gave you about [***well-formed***](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25830482/290085) should help you learn about this concept in general so you'll be able to evaluate your options better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your XML corrected to be [*well-formed*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25830482/290085):

```
<Item id="36">
    <name>Electrical and lighting - Exterior lighting</name>
    <note>&lt;123comments></note>
    <info id="code">&amp;*&amp;^&lt;samp&amp;*></info>
</Item>
```

**Notes:**

- `<` must be escaped as `&lt;` unless it's beginning a tag.
- `&` must be escaped as `&amp;` unless it's beginning an entity.

For further details on which characters must be escaped in XML, see [Simplified XML Escaping](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46637835/290085).

Answer (score 0):

I hope this works for you.

The problem is inside the info and note tags, the value can't have  < or >, so you should try to encode the value of that tag.

Comment: do you have a sample on how to do that? do I need to look for each tag to check the values?

Comment: Sure, the tags that you should encode are: note and info tag. Because the value the have are invalid for xml. Too, in order to solved that. Encode does values. I personally use Base64 encoding. In c# you can achieve that in the example of these old answer:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/11743162/10631412