# Unable to get response from FreshDesk API in proxy mode {"code" : "invalid_credentials", "message" : "You need to be logged in to perform action"}

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, freshdesk

So I'm using FreshDesk API and able to get the response using request module, But whenever I'm using proxy servers  I'm unable to get the response.

```
import base64
import requests
import os
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
import ssl
method = "get"
url = "https://mycompanydomain.freshdesk.com/api/v2/tickets"
apiKey = "XXXXXXXXX"
secret = "x"
os.environ["REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE"] = "Path to CA Certs"
auth = HTTPBasicAuth(apiKey, secret)
rsp = requests.request(method, url, headers=None, auth=auth)
print(rsp.text)
```

But whenever I'm using the proxy server in my organization, I'm getting an error message as **{"code":"invalid_credentials","message":"You have to be logged in to perform this action."}**

Code which I'm using for the proxy servers

```
import base64
import requests
import http.client
import urllib.parse
method = "get"
apiKey = "XXXXXXXX"
secret = "x"
url = "https://mycompanydomain.freshdesk.com/api/v2/tickets"
cred= '{}:{}'.format(apiKey, secret)
cred =  base64.b64encode(cred.encode('utf-8')).decode('utf-8')
authorization_headers = {
        'Proxy-Authorization': 'Basic {}'.format(cred)
}
conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection("11.125.250.121", 3128)
conn.set_tunnel("mycompanydomain.freshdesk.com", headers = authorization_headers)
headers = { 'Content-Type' : 'application/json' }
conn.request("GET", "/api/v2/tickets",headers = headers)
res = conn.getresponse()
data = res.read()
print(data.decode("utf-8"))
```

FreshDesk API Docs for using their API

```
curl -v -u abcdefghij1234567890:X -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X GET 'https://domain.freshdesk.com/api/v2/tickets'
```

Any possible way to resolve this error?

Comment: make sure you have correct apiKey and secret

Comment: Apikey and secret is correct for sure @Sabil

Answer (score 1):

Encoding the api key with the x for example as follows: someapikey:x helps.

See link:
[How do I encode and decode a base64 string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11743160/how-do-i-encode-and-decode-a-base64-string)

Also see FreshDesk api doc:
https://developers.freshdesk.com/api/#authentication
See the Note which says Encode if plain api key does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a bit of a guess, I haven't actually tried it but I do use Freshdesk, and I should be using their API.

Here is a link to the Freshdesk API:
https://support.freshdesk.com/support/solutions/articles/216548-create-and-update-tickets-with-custom-fields-using-api

I would try to taking out the "-H "Content-Type: application/json" to better match the suggested code. I would add the Content Type for POSTS not GETs in most cases, unless the API specifically calls for it. Try it and let us know how it works.

```
curl -u API_KEY:X -X GET https://domain.freshdesk.com/api/v2/ticket_fields
```

Comment: I tried with the above-mentioned method it didn't work either.

Comment: Hmm. Thank you for the update. I have had good luck with their support. Try to tell them, you might be running into a bug. They happen time to time. I wonder if there is an issue with a special character in your secret... Good Luck