# how to read in excel file in convert row with image to Base64 in C#

Tags: c#, excel

i have in excel file f1.xlsx like

a                b

image 1    banane

image 2    pomme

i wanted to read to file in c sharp (c#) and convert image to  Base64
could you help me please

Comment: You can use VSTO to develop an Excel Add-In which would make accessing .xlsx files easier for C# try learning that first and when you have some problems. Lookup some VBA (Excel macros) materials how to manipulate Excel spreadsheets programmatically

Comment: also it is expected from the person who asks questions to do some research first and try things, what have you tried so far?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ClosedXML](https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML) for reading excel files.
You can write a loop to iterate the rows and access each column of your excel files and cast them to anything you want. 
For base64 encoding and decoding, Check this out : [Base64 encode/decode](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11743162/14274238)

Comment: Thanks for your response
just can your right me an exemple with code please; I am new developer in c Sharp. 
thanaks for your help