# Send a bytes image to a api

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

i have an api that recieves an image in byte, but for some reason to the api arrives an empty parameter, what do i am doing wrong?

i send this from postman to the api, the image is the only parameter that doesnt arrive correctly

[image]

[image]

Comment: What type is the vac_imagen parameter? Try changing it to a string and converting after? 
Dim vOut() As Byte = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(vac_imagen)

Comment: my vac_imagen parameter is defined like this Public Property vac_imagen As Byte()

Comment: i tried using "Dim imagenenbytes as Byte()= System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(vac_imagen)" but when i want to became the bytes array into a image using  "Dim Imagenreducida as Image = DirectCast(New ImageConverter().ConvertFrom(imagenenbytes), Image)" it says me invalid parameter

Comment: It looks like you should expect a Base64 encoded string.

Comment: how do i do that?

Comment: @AgustinCoronel `how do i do that?` Take a look at :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11743160/how-do-i-encode-and-decode-a-base64-string