# Azure Queue Trigger reaches MaxDequeueCount immediately

Tags: .net, azure, azure-functions, azure-queues, azure-triggers

I have an azure queue trigger set up:

```
    [FunctionName("TransformData")]
    public async Task Transform(
        [QueueTrigger("product-prices")] string message)
    {
        await TransformAndLoadData(message);
    }
```

Whenever I add items to the queue via the QueueClient:
(RawQueueData splits items into message batches)

```
    var rawQueueData = new RawQueueData<T>(data);

    var sendMessageTasks = rawQueueData.Messages
        .Select(m => _queueClient.SendMessageAsync(m));
    
    await Task.WhenAll(sendMessageTasks);
```

Or move the messages from **product-prices-poison** back to **product-prices** queue (using Azure Storage Explorer), **the trigger immediately fails with:**

> Message has reached MaxDequeueCount of 5. Moving message to queue product-prices-poison.

Passing items synchronously also yields the same problem.

The only time I can successfully get the trigger to fire and process items is when I create a message with Azure Storage Explorer manually.

Increasing MaxDequeueCount, or batch size **does not** make a difference. The message after doing the former then is:

> Message has reached MaxDequeueCount of 100000. Moving message to queue product-prices-poison.

**I can also manually dequeue items by using the QueueClient without any issues.**

I have also tried changing the type of object I am receiving to QueueMessage, object and string.
Most other solutions seem to focus on updating the package (the one I am using the latest - stable 12.8.0).

EDIT:
host.json:

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "extensions": {
    "blobs": {
      "maxDegreeOfParallelism": "4"
    },
    "queues": {
      "maxDequeueCount": 5
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question and include host.json settings.

Comment: @GauravMantri thank you, I have posted the answer for this particular case below.

Answer (score 9):

Thank you for being my rubber duck.

After writing I soon realized the only different thing between azure storage explorer's "New Message" was the encoding.

**After switching the messages encoding to Base64 it started working.**

Comment: For reference, this started happening with a new version of the client library (see https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/10242). Whilst I'm at it, in case anyone finds it useful, here's a good answer on how to Base64 encode a string: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11743162/50151